# tcp.length and tcp.data wireshark filters

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I was playing with Wireshark and noticed two filters: `tcp.len` and `tcp.data`. What is the difference between the two? As far as I know, the `tcp.len` (length) field tells how many bytes of data travel within a segment, correct?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply put, `tcp.len` filters the length of TCP segment data in bytes, while `tcp.data` (or `tcp.segment_data` in newer versions of Wireshark) filters for the actual data (sequence of bytes) within the TCP segment data.

**Example:**

- `tcp.len == 1`

  - Filters for TCP segment data that is exactly 1 byte in length
- `tcp.segment_data contains 49:27:6d:20:64:61:74:61`

  - Filters for TCP segment data that contains the hexadecimal sequence of 49:27:6d:20:64:61:74:61

[Quick reference for TCP filters](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/t/tcp.html)