# Wireshark tcp.len and data.len missmatch

Tags: tcp, wireshark, mtu, pcap

What is the difference between `tcp.len` and `data.len` filters? I thought that both mean data size traveling in the segment (not including `TCP header`). I have a problem related to `MTU` issue and I'm trying to figure if data size from application layer is greater than the `MSS` announced by the server.

The capture shows some TCP packets encapsulating 1434 Bytes:

[image]

But the TCP layer analysis displays the same TCP packets with `len = 1448`

[image]

I think that this TCP segment is encapsulating 1448 Bytes. 1448B plus 32B of TCP header (some TCP options are enabled) plus 20B of IP Header = 1500 Bytes as it is displayed in the analysis of the IP layer.

So I have a question related to this one about `MSS clamping`. LAN clients are connected to the router using `Ethernet` with MTU = 1500 Bytes and router is connected to the Internet using `PPPoE` with MTU = 1492 Bytes. The router is manipulating `MSS` field in every TCP packet with `SYN flag` enabled in both directions, this is known as `MSS clamping`. This way LAN clients receive MSS = 1452 from servers on the Internet and the servers receive MSS = 1452 from the LAN clients.

But what happens if server announces MSS < 1452? LAN clients will receive MSS = 1452 from the server so only `PMTUD` can work here?

Comment: Have you read https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/7480/tcp-length-and-tcp-data-wireshark-filters ?

Comment: Yes and i wanted to say `data.len` instead `tcp.data`.  I have just edited the question. Should `data.len` and `tcp.len` match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the server's MSS is less than 1452, the router should not touch the MSS. The client will see the correct value sent by the server.

`tcp.len` and `data.len` will match if Wireshark does not interpret the data in the TCP stream. If wireshark can make sense of the data, it can update `data.len`. They don't have to match.

For example, in the case of HTTP, `data.len` can contain the total length of an HTTP POST request reassembled from which is spread over multiple TCP segments.